# How to delete python interpreters

Tags: macos, python, homebrew, pycharm

So, I made a few bummers while installing latest version of Python. Somehow I have managed to install Python more than once, and now I have several Python interpreters lying around (at least I have a bunch of them listing in Pycharm). I have several different versions of Python 3.4 (one that is called 3.4M?)

I feel like that's a waste of memory. So, can I get rid of the ones I don't use? I would like to only have the System Python (2.7.5) and latest.

I'm on mac os X. I have no idea how I managed to install so many versions of Python, but I think I was following a few tutorials way back and used brew to install python more than once? But that should probably just have overwritten the Python I have.

I'm sorry if I'm unclear, I'm not familiar with Python and its structure, and I hoped you guys would shed some light on it for me...

brew list:

```
atk         fontconfig      gmp4            libgpg-error

mercurial       ossp-uuid       python          smpeg

autoconf        freetype        gobject-introspection   libksba         

mongodb         pango           python3         sqlite

automake        gcc46           gtk+            libmpc08        

mpfr2           pixman          readline        webp

boost           gdbm            harfbuzz        libpng          

mysql           pkg-config      sdl         wget

cairo           gdk-pixbuf      icu4c           libtiff         

node            portmidi        sdl_image       xz

cloog-ppl015        gettext         jpeg            libtool         

openssl         postgresql      sdl_mixer

cmake           glib            libffi          libyaml         

openssl098      ppl011          sdl_ttf
```

which -a python:

```
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Pycharm lists these (some of them are virtual environments):

[image: Pycharm]

Comment: That seems normal. Which ones does pycharm list? They certainly didn't come from Brew then.

Comment: added a pic above!

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, the Pycharm list of interpreters is only a list of available python interpreters. It also lists those that were created as virtual environments, as you noted.

You can safely remove those in the list without affecting your actual python installs. This is done by clicking on the **gear** to the right of the list and selecting the **More...** option

From the pop-up window, you can then delete any of the listed interpreters you want.

If you want to remove the homebrew versions of python you can use the following commands in terminal:

Python 2.x

```
brew remove python
```

Python 3.x

```
brew remove python3
```